# Как добавить в ListView определенные файлы

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Как при помощи `Button` сделать возможность добавлять сразу множество файлов только формата mp3 в компонент `ListView`?

Comment: А вашу попытку это реализовать можно увидеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложу такой вариант: добавляем на форму `Button` и `ListView`. Делаем обработчик на клик по кнопке:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog folderPicker = new FolderBrowserDialog(); // открываем папку
    if (folderPicker.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // если выбрали
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear(); // очищаем наш список

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPicker.SelectedPath); // берем все файлы
        foreach (string file in files) // пробегаем по списку
        {
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(file); // берем расширение
            if (extension != null && extension.Contains("mp3")) // если mp3
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file); // берем имя
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(fileName); // создаем запись
                item.Tag = file;
                listView1.Items.Add(item); // добавляем в наш список
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Дополнительные ссылки:

- [Окно выбора директории FolderBrowserDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Метод Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Метод Path.GetExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Метод Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx)